# How do i change variables inside classes? in python

Tags: python

I've started coding an idle game but I will put some type of input in later.

My problem is that my `class` stockpiles doesn't add `int`'s from `def` chop/mine to my `variable` "SP_wood/SP_stone", it's just replacing the `variable` with the number it got from `def` chop/mine. I've tried to give the int straight to `def` addwood/addstone but that didn't work for me. The `+=` should work and add the two together. Should i make the `variable` outside the `class` and make it `global`?

```
import random
import time
idle = True


class Taskassigner:
    def __init__(self, tasknum):
        self.tasknum = tasknum
    def choosejob(self):
        if self.tasknum == 1:
            self.chop()
        if self.tasknum == 2:
            self.mine()
    def chop(self):
        wood = random.randint(1, 10)
        print('chopping wood')
        time.sleep(1.5)
        print('you got', wood)
        Stockpile(wood, 0)
        time.sleep(0.75)
    def mine(self):
        stone = random.randint(1, 10)
        print('mining for stone')
        time.sleep(1.5)
        print('you got', stone)
        Stockpile(0, stone)
        time.sleep(0.75)

class Stockpile:
    def __init__(self, wood, stone):
        self.wood = wood
        self.stone = stone
        self.SP_wood = 0
        self.SP_stone = 0
        self.Addwood(self.wood)
        self.Addstone(self.stone)
        self.check_wood()
        self.check_stone()
    def Addwood(self, addwood):
        self.addwood = addwood
        self.SP_wood += self.addwood
    def Addstone(self, addstone):
        self.addstone = addstone
        self.SP_stone += self.addstone
    def check_wood(self):
        print(self.SP_wood)
    def check_stone(self):
        print(self.SP_stone)


while idle:
    taskchance = random.randint(0, 100)
    if taskchance < 50:
        tasknum = random.randint(0, 2)
        job = Taskassigner(tasknum)
        job.choosejob()

    else:
        print('idle')
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: this is very nice code for a 14 y/o keep it up  :)

Comment: Welcome to SO and Coding! I did a bit of cleanup on the question, make sure I didn't edit out anything important.

Comment: thank you. Im sorry if i went against the rules a bit, i should of read them first. (if there is any)

Comment: Also, the question can be more description maybe something like "How to access and increment variables inside a python class".

Comment: note that `random.randint` includes both endpoints, so what you presumably think is a coinflip is actually weighted towards "No". `len(range(0, 50)) < len(range(50, 101))`

Answer (score 3):

I'd change a few things, mostly because you're making this harder than it needs to be. It doesn't look like your `TaskAssigner` really needs to hold state, so let's refactor it a bit to basically be a function factory. Then let's change those functions so they'll work on our newly refactored `Stockpile` class. Great job encapsulating, though!!!

```
def taskassigner(tasknum):
    """Function factory for tasks

    taskassigner(1) --> mine
    taskassigner(2) --> chop
    """

    def mine(stockpile):
        stockpile.stone += random.randint(1,10)
    def chop(stockpile):
        stockpile.wood += random.randint(1,10)

    tasks = [None, chop, mine]
    return tasks[tasknum]

class Stockpile(object):
    def __init__(self, wood, stone):
        self.wood = wood
        self.stone = stone
        # it's not really clear what SP_wood and SP_stone do
        # so I'm not sure if you actually need them!
```

Since `taskassigner` is now a function factory instead of a class, our calling signature looks a little different, too.

```
STARTING_WOOD, STARTING_STONE = 10, 10  # or whatever...
idle = True

player_stockpile = Stockpile(STARTING_WOOD, STARTING_STONE)
while idle:
    if random.randint(0, 1):  # since it's a coinflip, this is easier
        task_num = random.randint(1, 2)
        task = taskassigner(task_num)  # task is now one of your functions
        task(player_stockpile)
    else:
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

This all being said, it seems like you should be using separate modules for this!

```
# /main.py
import tasks
import time

STARTING_STONE, STARTING_WOOD = 10, 10
idle = True


class Stockpile(object):
    # defined as above


player_stockpile = Stockpile(STARTING_WOOD, STARTING_STONE)
while idle:
    if random.choice((True, False)):
        task = random.choice(tasks.tasklist)
        task(player_stockpile)
    else:
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

```
# /tasks.py
def mine(stockpile):
    stockpile.stone += random.randint(1,10)

def chop(stockpile):
    stockpile.wood += random.randint(1,10)

tasklist = [mine, chop]
```

Comment: lol apparently i really need to go eat something ... my brain is shutting down :P

Comment: it says no module named tasks. what axactl do i do im confused could you plz help?

Comment: the comment lines at the top of each of those bottom snippets are filenames. If you have some root directory `.../` you should have `.../main.py` importing `tasks`, which is `.../tasks.py`

Comment: could you please put it all into one big paragraph for me plz?
i dont undertand it

Comment: thank you very much. i like what you did with my idea.

Answer (score 0):

you need to keep your stockpile separate (but you should probably pass it around rather than make it global)

```
import random
import time
idle = True


class Taskassigner:
    def __init__(self, tasknum,stockpile):
        self.tasknum = tasknum
        self.stockpile = stockpile
    def choosejob(self):
        if self.tasknum == 1:
            self.chop()
        if self.tasknum == 2:
            self.mine()
    def chop(self):
        wood = random.randint(1, 10)
        print('chopping wood')
        time.sleep(1.5)
        print('you got', wood)
        self.stockpile.AddWood(wood)
        time.sleep(0.75)
    def mine(self):
        stone = random.randint(1, 10)
        print('mining for stone')
        time.sleep(1.5)
        print('you got', stone)
        self.stockpile.AddStone(stone)
        time.sleep(0.75)

class Stockpile:
    def __init__(self, wood, stone):
        self.wood = wood
        self.stone = stone
        self.SP_wood = 0
        self.SP_stone = 0
        self.Addwood(self.wood)
        self.Addstone(self.stone)
        self.check_wood()
        self.check_stone()
    def Addwood(self, addwood):
        self.addwood = addwood
        self.SP_wood += self.addwood
    def Addstone(self, addstone):
        self.addstone = addstone
        self.SP_stone += self.addstone
    def check_wood(self):
        print(self.SP_wood)
    def check_stone(self):
        print(self.SP_stone)

player_stockpile = Stockpile(0,0)
while idle:
    taskchance = random.randint(0, 100)
    if taskchance < 50:
        tasknum = random.randint(0, 2)
        #be sure to pass in the player stockpile
        job = Taskassigner(tasknum,player_stockpile)
        job.choosejob()

    else:
        print('idle')
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Could you plz tell me what you did there? i knida don't understand. sorry

Comment: the player stockpile is initialized before the loop ... then passed into the taskassigner... and instead of creating a new stockpile each time you simply AddWood or Stone to the existing stockpile

Comment: do i still need the stockpile class then? if so what for?