# I can't get a defined var outside a class to add with a var defined inside the class

Tags: python, class

i posted this a while ago but i've cleaned it a bit and since then, the problem is still here because no one really gave a right answer.
so what my problem is, is that my varibles that were defined outside the class and loop `stonepile` and `woodpile` (that are inside a class) aren't adding `stone`/`wood` (which are also inside the same class) to itself multiple times, i know this because i get the `stonepile`/`woodpile` to be printed. i have tested that the problem is actually the `stonepile`/`woodpile` at the begining being reset every time it is told to add `stone`/`wood` to `stonepile`/`woodpile`. i know this because i did this with them:

```
y = random.randint(1,5)
x = random.randint(1,5)
woodpile = y
stonepile = x
```

and the results were that if the stone mined was 1 and the randint for x was 5, it would print 6. or something similar.
So is there any way this can be fixed please?

the whole code here:

```
import random
import time
idle = True
woodpile = 0
stonepile = 0

while True:
    class Taskassigner:
        def __init__(self,tasknum,stonepile,woodpile):
            self.tasknum = tasknum
            self.woodpile = woodpile
            self.stonepile = stonepile
        def choosejob(self,stonepile,woodpile):
            if self.tasknum == 1:
                self.chop(woodpile)
            if self.tasknum == 2:
                self.mine(stonepile)
        def chop(self,woodpile):
            wood = random.randint(1, 10)
            print('chopping wood')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            print('you got', wood)
            woodpile += wood
            print(woodpile)
            time.sleep(0.75)
        def mine(self,stonepile):
            stone = random.randint(1, 10)
            print('mining for stone')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            print('you got', stone)
            stonepile += stone
            print(stonepile)
            time.sleep(0.75)

    while idle:
        taskchance = random.randint(0,1)
        if taskchance == 1:
            tasknum = random.randint(0,2)
            job = Taskassigner(tasknum,stonepile,woodpile)
            job.choosejob(stonepile,woodpile)
            print
        else:
            print('idle')
            time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Why is your class definition *inside* of a loop?

Comment: in your `__init__()` you are assigning `self.woodpile` two consecutive times, why?

Comment: i fixed it, but its still not doing what i want it doing

Comment: Hey @FlyingNat , I was the one who answered your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245153/how-do-i-change-variables-inside-classes-in-python). What did I leave unclear?

Comment: Hello again, well i probably didn't make myself clear, i just wanted to get this working so i know i can code things right and make it work the way i want it to work. im sorry because i feel like you will not like me because i didn't use your idea. i am a teen so please excuse my grammar and my childishness. please read the question if you wanna know my issue.

Comment: Im sorry @ScottHunter, but what are you saying?

Comment: @FlyingNat @ScottHunter is asking why use the `while True` to define the Class? That loop doesn't appear to be necessary

Comment: ah, well i put the class in the loop to try and stop the var's stonepile and woodpile being REdefined, so if i defined the var's outside the loop i thought it might work. this is my problem, can you fix it please?

Comment: Did i accidently delete your comment @Samcd? either way, could you turn it into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify a global in a function (or a class function), you need to use global

```
foo = 0
def afunc():
    global foo
    foo = 1

afunc()
print foo
```

The names of your globals are the same as inside of the class. I noticed some places where you done `woodpile += wood` when you might have wanted `self.woodpile += wood`

Comment: Thank you, i will improve my coding and if it works i'll approve of the answer. Thank you again.

Comment: although this will work, it's a poor design choice. You should avoid `global` whenever you can, because it breaks encapsulation.

Comment: IT WORKS!!! Thank you for your help. I made both variables global inside the class but it came up with this: "SyntaxError: name 'woodpile' is paramerter and global." so i removed both variables from all parameter of the class and now it works how i want it to

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out a way to instantiate the variable outside of the `while idle` loop. I would try not including tasknum as one of your `__init__` input variables

```
class Taskassigner:
        def __init__(self,stonepile,woodpile):
            self.tasknum = 0
            self.woodpile = woodpile
            self.stonepile = stonepile
```

also since you can't chop stone or mine wood, you don't have to include them in all your methods.
i.e.

```
def chop(self):
            wood = random.randint(1, 10)
            print('chopping wood')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            print('you got', wood)
            self.woodpile += wood
            print(self.woodpile)
            time.sleep(0.75)

def choosejob(self):
            if self.tasknum == 1:
                self.chop()
            if self.tasknum == 2:
                self.mine()
```

then you can call:

```
job = Taskassigner(tasknum,stonepile,woodpile)

while idle:
        taskchance = random.randint(0,1)
        if taskchance == 1:
            job.tasknum = random.randint(0,2)
            job.choosejob()
            print
        else:
            print('idle')
            time.sleep
            (0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how my working code looks:

```
import random
import time
idle = True
woodpile=0
stonepile=0


class Taskassigner:
    def __init__(self,tasknum):

        self.tasknum = tasknum
        self.choosejob(tasknum)
    def choosejob(self,tasknum):

        if self.tasknum == 1:
            self.chop()
        if self.tasknum == 2:
            self.mine()
    def chop(self):

        global woodpile
        wood = random.randint(1, 10)
        print('chopping wood')
        time.sleep(1.5)
        print('you got', wood)
        woodpile += wood
        print(woodpile)
        time.sleep(0.75)
    def mine(self):

        global stonepile
        stone = random.randint(1, 10)
        print('mining for stone')
        time.sleep(1.5)
        print('you got', stone)
        stonepile += stone
        print(stonepile)
        time.sleep(0.75)


while idle:

    taskchance = random.randint(0,1)
    if taskchance == 1:
        tasknum = random.randint(0,2)
        Taskassigner(tasknum)
    else:
        print('idle')
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with this? Is there something i can tighten? please feedback on my working code

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think you're trying to do:

```
woodpile = 0
stonepile = 0

some_task = TaskAssigner(...)
some_task.chop()

woodpile == 3  # True
```

You really don't WANT this to be the case. You never want your methods or functions affecting things they're not explicitly handed, because it makes debugging very *very* hard. Instead you should do something like:

```
class Stockpile(object):
    def __init__(self, starting_wood=0, starting_stone=0):
        self.woodpile = starting_wood
        self.stonepile = starting_stone

class TaskAssigner(object):
    def __init__(self, stockpile):
        self.stockpile = stockpile

    def mine(self):
        quantity = random.randint(1,5)
        self.stockpile.stonepile += quantity

    def chop(self):
        quantity = random.randint(1,5)
        self.stockpile.woodpile += quantity

    def do_task(self):
        if random.randint(0, 1):  # 50% chance
            random.choice([self.mine, self.chop])()
            # do either self.mine or self.chop

stockpile = Stockpile()

taskmaster = TaskAssigner(stockpile)

while True:
    if idle:
        taskmaster.do_task()
```

You could probably make this a bit more modular by doing something like:

```
from types import MethodType
import random

class TaskAssigner(object):
    def __init__(self, stockpile):
        self.stockpile = stockpile
        self.tasks = []

    def make_task(self, attr_to_change, delta_min, delta_max, f_name):
        def f(self):
            qty = random.randint(delta_min, delta_max)
            new_total = getattr(self.stockpile, attr_to_change) + qty
            setattr(self.stockpile, attr_to_change, new_total)
        f.__name__ = f_name
        f = MethodType(f, self)
        setattr(self, f_name, f)
        self.tasks.append(f)

    def do_task(self):
        if random.randint(0, 1):
            random.choice(self.tasks)()
```

Then you can do:

```
class Stockpile(object):
    def __init__(self, starting_wood=0, starting_stone=0, starting_grain=0):
        self.woodpile = starting_wood
        self.stonepile = starting_stone
        self.grainsilo = starting_grain

stockpile = Stockpile()
tasks = TaskAssigner(stockpile)

tasks.make_task('woodpile', 1, 5, 'chop_wood')
tasks.make_task('stonepile', 1, 5, 'mine_stone')
tasks.make_task('grainsilo', 2, 10, 'harvest_grain')

tasks.harvest_grain()  # adds to stockpile.grain_silo!
tasks.do_task()  # 50% does nothing, 50% does one of the three!
```

But be aware that this is pretty advanced and unless you *deeply* understand it, I would strongly recommend that you don't try this kind of metaprogramming at this time

Comment: i fixed it up a tiny bit and i got this still:                                               random.choice(self.mine, self.chop)()
TypeError: choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: @FlyingNat oops, fixed. I always think `random.choice` accepts `*args` but it actually accepts a single list of the options.

Comment: what is "object" for?

Comment: BTW, thank you for all your help! you were a massive help this time round. im not trying to be mean, sorry.

Comment: @FlyingNat You don't sound mean! Asking questions is good! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python should answer why I use `class Name(object)` instead of `class Name`. It's really just habit, now, since Python3 uses new-style classes by default.